# Kinect on Kuka LWR

Tags: ros, kinect, usb, kuka

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anybody succeeded in mounting a Kinect (or any piece of equipment using USB 2.0) as the end-effector of the Kuka LWR, and gotten the USB signal out through the cables that the arm provides?

I am running into problems (USB handshake failing) doing that, and was wondering if somebody has successfully done it and, if so, if they could please describe their setup. I am trying to avoid routing a cable through the outside of the arm.

(I know, it's not strictly a ROS question, but was hoping that the ever-expanding and enterprising ROS community might have some thoughts... :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123736/kinect-on-kuka-lwr/) by [cmatei](https://answers.ros.org/users/11381/cmatei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen some similar issues when trying to extend the USB cable on the Kinect; in particular when mounting a Kinect on a PR2.

In particular, the USB cable on the Kinect is very close to the maximum length allowed by the spec, and this can cause signal integrity and delay problems if cable extenders are used.

The common solution to this that I've seen is to cut and shorten the Kinect cable. This is also a good chance to replace the pesky non-standard kinect connector with a standard USB connector and a 12V power connector for your system.

If you're just interested in testing the cable integrity, I've often found it useful to plug in a common USB device such as a thumb drive or a cell phone, and verify that it shows up and works on the USB host.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0